# setTimeout with Bootstrap Modal not displaying after time out

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, settimeout

I'm trying to delay showing a Bootstrap modal until 5 seconds have passed. Here is the section of my code. It seems write from what I have read on MDN. The modal does not appear after any amount of time. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var timeout;
  function modalAlert(message){
        $("#myModalLabel").text("Hey Look!")
        $('.modal-body').html("<img src='"+message+"'>");
        timeout = window.setTimeout(showModal,5000);

  }
  function showModal(){
    console.log("HERE")
    $("#myModal").modal('show')
  }
```

Vijay Ramamurthy helped me find the solution:

```
var timeout;
  function modalAlert(message){
        $("#myModalLabel").text("Hey Look!")
        $('.modal-body').html("<img src='"+message+"'>");
        window.setTimeout(function(){showModal();},5000);

  }
  function showModal(){
    console.log("HERE")
    $("#myModal").modal('show')
  }
```

Comment: End up i manage to fix the issue by just arranging the sequence of my javascript tag. Previously setTimeout is place before modal(); it works after setTimeout place after modal()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "shown" event handler to register a timeout on the modal and then hide it. You can chain the functions together since it's a jQuery plugin.

```
$("#myModal").modal("show").on("shown", function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $("#myModal").modal("hide");
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Just for future reference, since the question isn't referring to a specific bootstrap version. In bootstrap 3 the event isn't called `shown`, it is called `shown.bs.modal`.

Answer (score 2):

try making the last line in the modalAlert function

```
timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {showModal();}, 5000);
```

Comment: That didn't work. It's weird when I paste your method or mine into the chrome console it works just fine.

Comment: Wait I just figured it out. remove the timeout= and it works fine. Thanks for your help! added the working solution to my question.

Comment: okay yeah to be honest i was confused about why you did that as I had never heard of it before, but i figured since it works in php it might work in javascript